# Why does my input (type=text) show a # automatically in URL

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container text-center">
          <h1 class="display-3">What's the weather</h1>
          <p class="lead"><strong>Enter the name of a city:</strong></p>
        <form>

<input type="text" placeholder="E.g. Cape Town, London" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" value="">

          <p class="lead">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="button">Submit</button>
          </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Whenever I click my "Submit" button I get the value and then "#". I have no Idea where it comes from. It shows in the URL (ie GET variable). I am using bootstrap. How can I get rid of the "#"?

Comment: Try giving the form action and method attributes

Comment: # is the default endpoint if you do not specify a form action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usu  method="" action="". method POST or GET

```
<form method="GET" action="">
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had to clear the variables first though